# Merging multiple 'dots' to a single face

Tags: vertices

I've taken a 3D scan using the iPhone Face ID. Importing the OBJ into blender reveals how the scan has been created, a couple of thousand vertices. Is there a way to merge these into a single object suitable for 3D printing?

[image: Lots of 'dots']

[image]

Comment: i can think of two ways to do that they are both really hacky and would require a lot of clean up, first "solution" is to add a skin modifier and then a remesh modifier this gives you a horrible looking result and also horrible geo next method gives you a similar result, second "solution" add a particle system and add metaballs as particle object's, i will post a real solution if i can think of a better way but your problem doesn't seem to be easily solvable.

Comment: There isn't really mesh surface but point cloud. Every 4 vertices from that cloud should be connected into a small quad, you don't merge them. Usually surface is better to generate with 3d scan software (since it has the data required for generating vertex colors based on scan source). If it can't for some reason MeshLab could be a better fit for this task than Blender